# how to access child of child node from firebase in a different module of android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok, so I have two modules in my app. One is for users, the other is for admin. the admin has to basically approve the user's registration when a user registers themselves, for this I made a simple logic when a user registers they're registered with an extra value `userStatus = "0"`, and the admin when clicks the approve button the value changes to "1" and they're allowed to log in. I'm using a Recycler View to show all the users from my database to the admin module but I wanna change a value that I'm not sure how to access,

below is my firebase database structure

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmYvR.png)
[complete picture of firebase database for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLvNB.png)

below is my code for the RecyclerView adapter class

```
package com.example.adminclient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecycler.MyViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<UserData> list;
    FirebaseDatabase fDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = fDB.getReference();



    public AdapterRecycler(Context context, ArrayList<UserData> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.users,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        UserData userData = list.get(position);

        holder.firstName.setText(userData.getFirstName());
        holder.address.setText(userData.getAddress());
        holder.emailAddress.setText(userData.getEmailAddress());
        holder.userStatus.setText(userData.getUserStatus());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView firstName, address, emailAddress, userStatus;
        Button approveUser;
        FirebaseDatabase fDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = fDB.getReference();


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            firstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstNametv);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addresstv);
            emailAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtv);
            approveUser = itemView. findViewById(R.id.approve);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userStatustv);
           // String firstNamedb = firstName.getText().toString();



            approveUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fDB.getReference().child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                reference.child("Users").child(???).child("userStatus").setValue("1");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });


                }
            });

        }


    }
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of Recycler View in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmpP4.jpg)

Below is the code for Recycler View class

```
package com.example.adminclient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VerifyUsers extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    AdapterRecycler adapterRecycler;
    ArrayList<UserData> list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_users);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userVerify);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterRecycler = new AdapterRecycler(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecycler);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                    UserData userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class);
                    list.add(userData);
                }
                adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

if there's anyone out there that understands my situation and problem please help me out.

I tried what I could on 'approve' button onclicklistener by adding a value event listener to it and retrieving from firebase database reference for the child but I have no clue on how to move forward from here.

```
approveUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        fDB.getReference().child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    reference.child("Users").child(???).child("userStatus").setValue("1");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
});
```

Below here is my UserData class

```
package com.example.adminclient;

import android.location.Address;

public class UserData {
    String firstName;
    String address;
    String emailAddress;

    String userStatus;





    public UserData() {
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {

        return firstName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {

        return address;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {

        return emailAddress;
    }

    public String getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: In simple words I wanna change the value of "userStatus" from recyclerView when "approve User" button is pressed. So, I want to access the second child in the firebase database (the one below Users) to change the value of third child "userStatus ; from 0 to 1".. I'm having trouble accessing the 2nd child since its not the same for all nodes and I have no clue as to how it should be done, does this clear the confusion?

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: I will be implementing firebase authentication in sign in and register class of user module as that comes after the user is approved by the admin. For now I've only taken user data through register class and put it in firebase realtime database..

Comment: What does `647e6uurr` represent? And what is the exact user you want to update? Or do you need to update them all?

Comment: 647e6uurr is random data meant to be the first name, I've ordered the users with their first names. I should order them with the phonenumber instead. and yes I wanna update all of the users when the approve button is clicked in recycler view infront of their card I'll show the complete picture of the firebase database in edit

Comment: So you have a button in front of each user and when pressed you need to change the value from 0 to 1?

Comment: Yes! is that possible Alex?

Comment: For sure there is. Show us also the content of your `UserData` class.

Comment: Done, I updated the post with UserData class, just as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to pass the entire `UserData` object from the `onBindViewHolder` to the `bindData` function that I have added inside the `MyViewHolder` class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    UserData userData = list.get(position);
    holder.bindData(userData); //
}
```

Once you have the `UserData` you can create a reference that point to the `userStatus` field and change the value:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView firstName, address, emailAddress, userStatus;
    Button approveUser;
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("Users");


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        firstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstNametv);
        address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addresstv);
        emailAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtv);
        approveUser = itemView. findViewById(R.id.approve);
        userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userStatustv);
    }


    //             
    public void bindData(UserData userData) {
        firstName.setText(userData.getFirstName());
        address.setText(userData.getAddress());
        emailAddress.setText(userData.getEmailAddress());
        userStatus.setText(userData.getUserStatus());

        approveUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String firstName = userData.getFirstName();
                usersRef.child(firstName).child("userStatus").setValue("1");
                //                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex it doesn't work either, as its throwing a bunch of errors, one of them being " cannot reslove userData" on "public void bindData(UserData userData)"...

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. I have added the method inside the constructor. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Ok so it wasn't working then I set '"holder.bindData(userData);"' in 'onBindViewHolder'... and it's working now exactly as I want it to. Alex Sir you're a genius.. you have no idea how much I appreciate this help. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, I forgot to call `bindData` method on the `holder` object. I just approved your edit. You're very welcome, axeem666.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line of code.

```
reference.child("Users").child(userData.getFirstName()).child("userStatus").setValue("1");
```

Comment: Its throwing me an error "Non-static method 'getFirstName()' cannot be referenced from a static context". making it a static method doesn't solve it.